# How to I open my child tab without closing my parent tab

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

This is only a part of my code, there are alot of tabs, but only a parent and a child, I haven't seen anyone on here who codes like me, they all use $. So I can't use their code and I'm new to coding so I can't decipher and re write their code. I hope you can understand what I've written here, it's for a game I play. It would be very nice if I could get an answer. :) Thanks. Also, if you need more information on certain lines od code, I'll add more info.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.className += " active";
}
function openArmor(evt, tabArmor) {
    var i, armorcontent, armorlinks;
    armorcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("armorcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < armorcontent.length; i++) {
        armorcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    armorlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("armorlinks");
    for (i = 0; i < armorlinks.length; i++) {
        armorlinks[i].className = armorlinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabArmor).style.display = "block";
    evt.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tabContent{
 display:none;
}
.armorcontent{
 display:none;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li{
 float: left;
}
li a:hover:not(.active){
 background-color: black;
 color: red;
}
#mainNav{
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #f7f5f3;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
}
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #f7f5f3;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
ul#mainNav{
 background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
footer{
 bottom: 0;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4);
 margin-left: 273px;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border-radius: 20px 0px;
}
section div{
 background-color: rgba(180, 0, 0, .6);
 padding: 8px 10px;
 height: 90%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
   <ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Armor')">Armor</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Weapons')">Weapons</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="Armor" class="armorcontent">
    <ul class="tab">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="armorlinks" onclick="openArmor(event, 'Adventurer')">Adventurer</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Adventurer" class="armorcontent">
                     <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Stats</th>
      <th>Set Effect</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Helemt</th>
      <td>DP</td>
      <td rowspan="16">Set Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Chest</th>
      <td>DP</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Gloves</th>
      <td>DP</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Shoes</th>
      <td>DP</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Item Effect</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Can you provide some example on jsbin or jsfiddle?
what do you mean "closing parent tab"

Comment: to switch, i would hide them all and then un-hide the one you need. that way, you don't have to worry about combinations.

Comment: Here's a very fundamental thing that you are not aware of is that to place comments in HTML you must wrap the comments like so: `<!--COMMENT-->` not `/*COMMENT*/` Provide a [mcve].

Comment: There we go, I fixed it, the snippets are all together, and completed. My apologies for not realising all this, thank you for helping me.

Comment: the $ is jquery and would save you a huge amount of effort  if you use jquery tabs at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Having said that, give your ul containers their own ids so you can limit the scope of actions being applied to the items of a specific ul

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sounds like good advise, I'll see what I come up with. :)

Comment: I fixed it by changing the Variable "i" to a different letter, like "a" It works without closing the parent tab now. xD Such an easy fix that I didn't even think about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a tab in a tab like I have all you need is to change the second functions var from "i" to "a" it separates the function and causes the parent tab to stop closing when the child tab is opened.